# django queryset filter check if ManyToMany Field contains specific object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these two models :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I want to get a queryset containing all the Projects with a specific user in the 'users' ManyToManyField

I tried this : `Project.objects.filter(users__contains=user)`, but it's not working

Does someone know how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you share your entire view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if filtering with id:

```
Project.objects.filter(users=search_id)
```

if filtering with user name:

```
Project.objects.filter(users__name__icontains=search_input)
```